# Error: Make directory (Path): Not a directory (in target 'Watch' from project (Project name))

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I have followed everything very thoroughly and in detail from this tutorial, but I get this error. I am still a beginner and I do not know how to fix this problem right now. I tried to also delete that folder via the terminal (https://www.raywenderlich.com/287-watchos-4-tutorial-part-1-getting-started), but this error still appears. 
This is how the error message looks like (take a lot at the image):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZhvb.jpg

And here you can see the whole code, I followed from the tutorial which is not much, though.
https://ufile.io/n8mvvnkx

I hope you can help me out.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Derived Data folder, clean and rebuild your project.